# Change menu text on hover

Tags: css, menu, mousehover

I wanted to change the text of my existing header menu on my site. Is there any way that this can be done so that when you hover over a menu item, the text changes?

I want to make sure that I'll be able to use the existing menu that I have in my header and if possible the existing class for the site nav.

Thanks all!

This is the existing code that we have in our theme.css for the site nav:

```
/*================ #Site Nav and Dropdowns ================*/
.site-nav--centered {
 padding-bottom: 22px;
}

/*================ Site Nav Links ================*/
.site-nav__link.site-nav--active-dropdown {
 border: none; 
 border-bottom: none;
 z-index: 2;
      }

.site-nav__link:focus .site-nav__label, .site- 
      nav__link:not([disabled]):hover .site-nav__label {
  border-bottom-color: none !important;
  color: #eae5d3}

@media only screen and (max-width: 989px) {
 .site-nav__link--button {
   font-size: calc(var(--font-size-base) * 1px); } }

.site-nav__link--button:focus, .site-nav__link--button:hover {
 color: var(--color-text-focus);
 }
```

Comment: Post your code please. See [mcve]

Comment: just added! let me know if anything else could help figure this out

Comment: You need to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pseudo-selector `:hover` to apply styles on hover. pair this with a transition and you can make some nice, modern things. example:

```
<style>
button {
   background-color: red;
}
button:hover {
   background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<button> Hover on me! </button>
```

you can use the before and after selectors to change the content with this. If not, you can use an mouse in and mouse out event listener and change the styles of the element accordingly.

Comment: Hey! How could I apply this to my existing .site-nav__link--button:focus, .site-nav__link--button:hover? Want to make sure each menu item has different text on the hover

Comment: hmm, i'm a little confused on what you mean? could you explain more? if you want, my discord is AwesomeDude3247#6805

Comment: so essentially, the change would be for my site's header: https://imgur.com/a/PRDZN71. Is there any way this can be applied to the existing header items? let me know if you need me to explain further!

Comment: ok, still kind of confused. just gonna go back to your original question. the event listener would look something like this for mouse on. `element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {element.innerHTML = "foo"}` and `element.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {element.innerHTML = "bar"}` for mouse out